# SP2010: How to automatically check in a document after X amount of time

Tags: workflow, sharepoint-server

In SP2010 I'm looking for a way to automatically check in a document using a system account if the user leaves it checked out for X amount of days. I imagine I'll probably have to use a VS workflow for  this, but I'm ok with that option if it's the only one.

Specifically, if a user uploads or modifies a document then forgets to check it in, I want to (ideally) do three things:

> 1. Check document state (checked in/out)
> 2. Wait X days, then send user an email with a link reminding them to check it in
> 3. Wait X days, then if no change just check in the document using a system account

Is there any way to do this? I'll take native functionality, code, or even a 3rd party product as an acceptable answer.

Comment: very interesting requirements, are you going to discard user's local change after X + X days?

Comment: Step 3 could be either to check IN the document or to discard the check-out. That's something I'd have to take to the business unit. My personal preference would be to discard the check-out in step 3.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably the simplest form would be a workflow.

Your logic would start when modified:

```
Set variable to Modified (modifieddate)
Set variable to Modified By (modifiedby)
If Checked Out By is not empty
Pause until X days
Email Checked Out User
Pause until X days

If Checked Out By is equal to modifiedby AND
If Modified is equal to modifieddate
Discard Checkout.
```

If you wanted to be more clever, I would suggest a timer job.

Comment: Interesting - I didn't think it would be possible with a Designer workflow but this just might work. If I can find a way to push this out to all libraries (maybe via a global workflow?) I think it would solve my need.

Comment: If you want to do this globally, I strongly suggest using a timer job instead. If it's only by one site, you may be able to get away with a site workflow.